# Linux: end running bash script when closing ssh session

Tags: bash, session, exit

When logged in via putty / ssh users start a bash script. Sometimes users just close the putty window and do not end the skript properly.

How can you force an end of script by session close ?

Answer (score 0):

To force the script to close when a user logs out:

1. edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.
2. Uncomment `KillUserProcesses=no`
3. Change it to `KillUserProcesses=yes`

I had mixed results when I used `$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` on CentOS 7.  Rebooting the server worked.

If you only want this to occur for certain users you can also uncomment `KillOnlyUsers=` and add the userid's.

**Resource**

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html